# PDF Reader in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, pdf, ios4

Since i am new to iphone domain., i want some best tutorial that how to make PDF Reader in iphone. Can anyone suggest me how to make PDF reader in iphone to view a locl PDF and the PDF file from internet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl]];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPDFFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TiledPDFView :  UIView {
    CGPDFPageRef pdfPage;
    CGFloat myScale;

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andScale:(CGFloat)scale;
- (void)setPage:(CGPDFPageRef)newPage;

@end



#import "TiledPDFView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation TiledPDFView


// Create a new TiledPDFView with the desired frame and scale.
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andScale:(CGFloat)scale{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

        CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];

        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 4;
        tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(512.0, 512.0);
        myScale = scale;
    }
    return self;
}

// Set the layer's class to be CATiledLayer.
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

// Set the CGPDFPageRef for the view.
- (void)setPage:(CGPDFPageRef)newPage
{
    CGPDFPageRelease(self->pdfPage);
    self->pdfPage = CGPDFPageRetain(newPage);
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    // UIView uses the existence of -drawRect: to determine if it should allow its CALayer
    // to be invalidated, which would then lead to the layer creating a backing store and
    // -drawLayer:inContext: being called.
    // By implementing an empty -drawRect: method, we allow UIKit to continue to implement
    // this logic, while doing our real drawing work inside of -drawLayer:inContext:
}


// Draw the CGPDFPageRef into the layer at the correct scale.
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // First fill the background with white.
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5);
    CGContextFillRect(context,self.bounds);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    // Flip the context so that the PDF page is rendered
    // right side up.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);


    // Scale the context so that the PDF page is rendered 
    // at the correct size for the zoom level.
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, myScale,myScale);    
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}

// Clean up.
- (void)dealloc {
    CGPDFPageRelease(pdfPage);

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Add this view to your view controller

Regards,
Shyam Parmar

Comment: this may help you
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html